# Sort Objects From a File

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object

(At time of posting, I do not have access to code, will add later)

I have an array of Employee objects, which hold a name, availability, and preferred hours. And I sort the objects by Alphabetical order, according to the employees name.

When the program starts, it checks the files, and if they are empty, it asks you how many employees, and then you proceed to fill in the data. And it sorts properly A-Z.

This issue comes that when I try to add a new employee, after resizing the array, it adds it to the end, even though the sort completes.

So it sorts the first time, but not again after re running the program. I will post the code when I get home, but wanted to see if anyone had any answers in the mean time. Thank you

```
static void employeeSort(Employee[] emply, int size)
{
    int i;
    Employee temp;

    boolean flag = true;

        while(flag)
        {   
            flag = false;
            for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {

                if (emply[i].getName().compareTo(emply[i+1].getName())>0)
                   {
                       System.out.println(emply[i].getName());
                       temp = emply[i];
                       emply[i] = emply[i+1];
                       emply[i+1] = temp;
                       flag = true;
                   }

            }   
        }

}
```

On the first run through, it sorts everything correctly, but once the array is read from a file, the program terminates in the sort. I tried implementing the priority queue, but i needed to make the Class comparable, and its already implemented Serializable.

```
public class Employee implements Serializable
{
int     prefHours;
String  name;
String  avail;

Employee( String nam, int hours, String aval )
{
    name = nam;
    prefHours = hours;
    avail = aval;
}

void prnEmpl()
{
    System.out.print("Name: " + name);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Prefered hours: " + prefHours);
    System.out.println(); 
    System.out.print("Availability: " + avail);
    System.out.println();
}

String getName()
{
    return name;
}

String getAvail()
{
    return avail;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Without your code it is hard to figure out what's the problem. As far as I understand I think you should use [java.util.PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) instead of `Array`.

Comment: I was able to get it to work, I couldn't get the PriorityQueue to work because I kept getting an error about it not being Comparable, and I couldnt find a way to make the class both Comparable and Serializable at the same time, cause I have limited info and experience with Java, but I managed to find another way to make it work, thank your for your help though.

Comment: You are welcome. Happy Coding...